# How can I slice each element of a numpy array of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, slice

Numpy has some very useful [string operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html), which vectorize the usual Python string operations.

Compared to these operation and to `pandas.str`, the numpy strings module seems to be missing a very important one: the ability to slice each string in the array. For example,

```
a = numpy.array(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'])
numpy.char.sliceStr(a, slice(1, 3))
>>> numpy.array(['el', 'ow', 're' 'ou'])
```

Am I missing some obvious method in the module with this functionality? Otherwise, is there a fast vectorized way to achieve this?

Comment: i am not sure what the question is. who is missing this feature?

Comment: Numpy's `routines.char` seems to be missing it. I edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: I've looked for this functionality as well. I think I've always ended up using some kind of loop.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
def slicer_vectorized(a,start,end):
    b = a.view((str,1)).reshape(len(a),-1)[:,start:end]
    return np.fromstring(b.tostring(),dtype=(str,end-start))
```

Sample run -

```
In [68]: a = np.array(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'])

In [69]: slicer_vectorized(a,1,3)
Out[69]: 
array(['el', 'ow', 're', 'ou'], 
      dtype='|S2')

In [70]: slicer_vectorized(a,0,3)
Out[70]: 
array(['hel', 'how', 'are', 'you'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Runtime test -

Testing out all the approaches posted by other authors that I could run at my end and also including the vectorized approach from earlier in this post.

Here's the timings -

```
In [53]: # Setup input array
    ...: a = np.array(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'])
    ...: a = np.repeat(a,10000)
    ...: 

# @Alberto Garcia-Raboso's answer
In [54]: %timeit slicer(1, 3)(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.5 ms per loop

# @hapaulj's answer
In [55]: %timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda x:x[1:3],1,1)(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop

# Using loop-comprehension
In [56]: %timeit np.array([i[1:3] for i in a])
100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop

# From this post
In [57]: %timeit slicer_vectorized(a,1,3)
1000 loops, best of 3: 787 µs per loop
```

Comment: Was this tested with Python 2.x or 3.x? With 3.5.2 I get `array([b'', b'', b'', b''], dtype='|S2')` as output?

Comment: @Bart This was with Python 2.7. Will see if the issue is there with Python 3.x. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: @Bart: I edited the code in this answer slightly to make it compatible with Python 3.  The problem was the used of `'S'` as the dtype, while Python 3 uses Unicode everywhere, so `'U'`.  Now it uses `str` as the dtype so it should work on all versions.

Comment: Nice trick. You can get almost 2x faster by using `.view()` again instead of `.tostring()`/`fromstring`. The second line can be replaced by: `return numpy.array(b).view((str,end-start)).flatten()`

Answer (score 4):

Most, if not all the functions in `np.char` apply existing `str` methods to each element of the array.  It's a little faster than direct iteration (or `vectorize`) but not drastically so.

There isn't a string slicer; at least not by that sort of name.  Closest is indexing with a slice:

```
In [274]: 'astring'[1:3]
Out[274]: 'st'
In [275]: 'astring'.__getitem__
Out[275]: <method-wrapper '__getitem__' of str object at 0xb3866c20>
In [276]: 'astring'.__getitem__(slice(1,4))
Out[276]: 'str'
```

An iterative approach can be with `frompyfunc` (which is also used by `vectorize`):

```
In [277]: a = numpy.array(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'])
In [278]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x:x[1:3],1,1)(a)
Out[278]: array(['el', 'ow', 're', 'ou'], dtype=object)
In [279]: np.frompyfunc(lambda x:x[1:3],1,1)(a).astype('U2')
Out[279]: 
array(['el', 'ow', 're', 'ou'], 
      dtype='<U2')
```

I could view it as a single character array, and slice that

```
In [289]: a.view('U1').reshape(4,-1)[:,1:3]
Out[289]: 
array([['e', 'l'],
       ['o', 'w'],
       ['r', 'e'],
       ['o', 'u']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

I still need to figure out how to convert it back to 'U2'.

```
In [290]: a.view('U1').reshape(4,-1)[:,1:3].copy().view('U2')
Out[290]: 
array([['el'],
       ['ow'],
       ['re'],
       ['ou']], 
      dtype='<U2')
```

The initial view step shows the databuffer as Py3 characters (these would be bytes in a `S` or Py2 string case):

```
In [284]: a.view('U1')
Out[284]: 
array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'o', 'w', '', '', 'a', 'r', 'e', '',
       '', 'y', 'o', 'u', '', ''], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Picking the 1:3 columns amounts to picking `a.view('U1')[[1,2,6,7,11,12,16,17]]` and then reshaping and view.  Without getting into details, I'm not surprised that it requires a copy.

Comment: `a.view('U1').reshape(len(a),-1)[:,1:3].astype(object).sum(axis=1)` works and is the clear winner in terms of performance --- see my answer.

Comment: It looks like you can convert your array from `U1` to `U2` with `view` if you make a copy first, but we shouldn't need the copy. In principle, this should just be a simple manipulation of strides, dimensions, and offsets, but I don't know if there's a way to do it like that without directly applying C routines.

Comment: tricky use of `.sum()`.  In this case it's the `string + string` concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting omission... I guess you can always write your own:

```
import numpy as np

def slicer(start=None, stop=None, step=1):
    return np.vectorize(lambda x: x[start:stop:step], otypes=[str])

a = np.array(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'])
print(slicer(1, 3)(a))    # => ['el' 'ow' 're' 'ou']
```

EDIT: Here are some benchmarks using the text of Ulysses by James Joyce. <strike>It seems the clear winner is @hpaulj's last strategy.</strike> @Divakar gets into the race improving on @hpaulj's last strategy.

```
import numpy as np
import requests

ulysses = requests.get('http://www.gutenberg.org/files/4300/4300-0.txt').text
a = np.array(ulysses.split())

# Ufunc
def slicer(start=None, stop=None, step=1):
    return np.vectorize(lambda x: x[start:stop:step], otypes=[str])

%timeit slicer(1, 3)(a)
# => 1 loop, best of 3: 221 ms per loop

# Non-mutating loop
def loop1(a):
    out = np.empty(len(a), dtype=object)
    for i, word in enumerate(a):
        out[i] = word[1:3]

%timeit loop1(a)
# => 1 loop, best of 3: 262 ms per loop

# Mutating loop
def loop2(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = a[i][1:3]

b = a.copy()
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 loop2(b)
# 1 loop, best of 1: 285 ms per loop

# From @hpaulj's answer
%timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda x:x[1:3],1,1)(a)
# => 10 loops, best of 3: 141 ms per loop

%timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda x:x[1:3],1,1)(a).astype('U2')
# => 1 loop, best of 3: 170 ms per loop

%timeit a.view('U1').reshape(len(a),-1)[:,1:3].astype(object).sum(axis=1)
# => 10 loops, best of 3: 60.7 ms per loop

def slicer_vectorized(a,start,end):
    b = a.view('S1').reshape(len(a),-1)[:,start:end]
    return np.fromstring(b.tostring(),dtype='S'+str(end-start))

%timeit slicer_vectorized(a,1,3)
# => The slowest run took 5.34 times longer than the fastest.
#    This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
#    10 loops, best of 3: 16.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is slower than a regular loop though.

Comment: It is slightly faster than a loop on my machine (with a large array).

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, so far I've been transforming the numpy `array` to a pandas `Series` and back. It is not a pretty solution, but it works and it works relatively fast.

```
a = numpy.array(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'])
pandas.Series(a).str[1:3].values
array(['el', 'ow', 're', 'ou'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Actually when I timed it on a large array pandas was not faster for regular slicing (something like .str[1:5]). I even excluded the time for converting the array to series. It was faster for things like .str[::-1] though.

Comment: Pandas appears to use a lot of object arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree that this is an omission, which is why I opened up [PR #20694](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694). If that gets accepted, you will be able to do exactly what you propose, but under the slightly more conventional name of `np.char.slice_`:

```
>>> a = np.array(['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'])
>>> np.char.slice_(a, 1, 3)
array(['el', 'ow', 're' 'ou'])
```

The code in the PR is fully functional, so you can make a working copy of it, but it uses a couple of hacks to get around some limitations.

For this simple case, you can use simple slicing. Starting with numpy 1.23.0, you can view non-contiguous arrays under a dtype of different size ([PR #20722](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20722)). That means you can do

```
>>> a[:, None].view('U1')[:, 1:3].view('U2').squeeze()
array(['el', 'ow', 're' 'ou'])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great.

Comment: @MartínFixman. Thanks. It's been bothering me too. I'll let you know when it gets accepted :)