# numpy char.array get set of characters from a string

Tags: python, regex, string, numpy

this is my numpy.char.array

```
table = np.char.arrray([['/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=TMIN.NS&exchange=INSE'],
['/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=8KMS.BO&exchange=INB'],
['/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=ADRG.NS&exchange=INSE']],dtype='|S53')
```

how can i get the below desired output:

```
out = ['TMIN.NS','8KMS.BO','ADRG.NS']
```

with `table.find(".NS")`i can get the index position of `.NS`in the string. But how can i use this to get to the desired output?

```
In [69]: table.find(".NS")
Out[69]: 
       array([[36],
             [-1],
             [36],
             ..., 
             [36],
             [36],
             [36]])
```

the reason, simple index based selection does not work is because, the whole string is just single element. The shape of array is `(30L,1L)`

I can use `str` or `regex` on  individual string elements to get the desired output, but that will require running a for loop over the array. How can i do this in numpy alone? thanks.

edit_1/
this is how i can get the result though indexing but i cannot do it at the same time on the whole array

```
table[0][0][32:38]
Out[75]: 'TMIN.N'
```

Comment: Are the strings that you are looking for always of `7` characters? Would they always be followed by that string `'/finance/stocks/overview?symbol='`?

Comment: Yes, in this case, they will follow a fixed pattern.

Comment: And always of `7` characters?

Comment: Yes, the string to be selected will be of 7 characters. (there will be variation (atmost 8 characters where some tickers will be of 5 instead of 4 character length), but at this point, i will just ignore it since it will likely be may be about 2% of whole dataset).

Comment: The `char` functions (in this case methods of `chararray`) just apply the corresponding `string` method to each element of the array.  They don't speed things up much compared to an explicit loop.  I'd suggest apply your own string operation in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a vectorized slicing method of NumPy array of string dtypes from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39045337/3293881) -

```
In [149]: search_pattern = '/finance/stocks/overview?symbol='

In [150]: pruned_table = np.chararray.replace(table, search_pattern,'')

In [151]: slicer_vectorized(pruned_table, 0, 7)
Out[151]: 
array(['TMIN.NS', '8KMS.BO', 'ADRG.NS'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

---

Alternatively, since we know the strings that we are looking for would be right after the `search_pattern`, we can simply look for it right after the length of that pattern, like so -

```
In [167]: N  = len(search_pattern)

In [168]: slicer_vectorized(table, N,N+7)
Out[168]: 
array(['TMIN.NS', '8KMS.BO', 'ADRG.NS'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

Comment: you are simply the best.

Answer (score 1):

The `np.char` functions/methods don't speed things up much - they just loop through the elements apply the corresponding string method.

```
In [261]: timeit [astr.find(".NS") for astr in table.flat]
....
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.92 µs per loop
In [262]: timeit table.find(".NS")
....
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.6 µs per loop
```

So defining a simple function that isolates the desired substring (one of several possible routes),

```
def extract(astr):
    astr=astr.split('?')[1].split('&')[0]
    astr = astr.split('=')[1]
    return astr

In [268]: [extract(astr) for astr in table.flat]
Out[268]: ['TMIN.NS', '8KMS.BO', 'ADRG.NS']
In [269]: timeit [extract(astr) for astr in table.flat]
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.98 µs per loop
```

A general observation is that with small array/lists the list comprehension route is often faster than an equivalent array. Array operations get better with size.