# Most efficient way to convert empty(ish) strings to null

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series that contains both empty strings and strings with nothing but whitespace. I want to convert these to a 'null' value (e.g. None).

```
def empty_str_to_null(s):
    """Convert empty strings to None (null)"""
    s.loc[s.str.strip().str.len() == 0] = None
    return s

foo = pd.Series(np.repeat([1,2,3,'',None,np.NaN, '  ', '  a'],1E6))

>>> %time bar = empty_str_to_null(foo)
```

This works but isn't that fast.

```
CPU times: user 7.67 s, sys: 260 ms, total: 7.93 s
Wall time: 8.38 s
```

I will need to do this repeatedly for many different fields.

Is there a better (quicker) way?

Comment: Try `s.replace('', np.nan)`, I'm not sure it is vectored but I'm sure it's much faster.

Comment: Will that work with empty(ish) strings ... i.e. Where this is nothing but white space?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach -

```
def empty_str_to_null_slicer(s):
    a = s.values.astype(str)
    # slicer_vectorized from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39045337/
    mask = (slicer_vectorized(a,0,1)==' ') | (a=='')
    s[mask] = None
    return s
```

Sample run -

```
In [245]: s = pd.Series(np.repeat([1,'',' ',None,np.NaN],2))

In [246]: s
Out[246]: 
0       1
1       1
2        
3        
4        
5        
6    None
7    None
8     NaN
9     NaN
dtype: object

In [247]: a = s.values.astype(str)
     ...: mask = (slicer_vectorized(a,0,1)==' ') | (a=='')
     ...: s[mask] = None
     ...: 

In [248]: s
Out[248]: 
0       1
1       1
2    None
3    None
4    None
5    None
6    None
7    None
8     NaN
9     NaN
dtype: object
```

Runtime test -

Approaches -

```
# Original approach
def empty_str_to_null(s0):
    s = s0.copy()
    """Convert empty strings to None (null)"""
    s.loc[s.str.strip().str.len() == 0] = None
    return s

# Proposed approach
def empty_str_to_null_slicer(s0):
    s = s0.copy()
    a = s.values.astype(str)
    # slicer_vectorized from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39045337/3293881
    mask = (slicer_vectorized(a,0,1)==' ') | (a=='')
    s[mask] = None
    return s
```

Timings -

```
In [228]: foo = pd.Series(np.repeat([1,'',' ',None,np.NaN],1E6))

In [229]: %timeit empty_str_to_null(foo)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.17 s per loop

In [230]: %timeit empty_str_to_null_slicer(foo)
1 loop, best of 3: 573 ms per loop
```

Comment: Does `slicer_vectorized(a,0,1)==' '` just check for a single white space at the beginning of the string, or for any number of spaces? I tried reading your other answer and I might be misunderstanding.

Comment: @drstevok `a` is the string array. So, `slicer_vectorized(a,0,1)` is first character from every string in that array. `slicer_vectorized(a,0,2)` would be the first two characters  and so on. With `slicer_vectorized(a,0,1)==' '` , we are checking if the first character is a whitespace.

Comment: Thanks. From running the line profiler, it looks like the problem with my function is the `strip` step. I can't get your function to work if I do `slicer_vectorized(a,0,:)` ... was thinking of checking for the whole string being white space?

Comment: @drstevok Nah, it won't work that way. So, do you have strings that start with whitespace, but are still valid and are not to converted to `None`?

Comment: I've added an empty string to the example above that includes more than one white space. I'd like it to be converted to `None` too. Sorry I wasn't clear in the original post. I also tried `s.loc[s.str.isspace() == True] = None` followed by `s = s.replace('', None)` but it's still slow

Comment: @drstevok Sorry, I am not really familiar with `isspace` or `replace`. But, for your given sample, `slicer_vectorized` should work just fine.

Comment: @drstevok Don't think you answered if `slicer_vectorized` worked for you? :)

Comment: Almost, I have modified the original qn to explain the issue with multiple white space, and was waiting to see if anyone had an alternative idea. Is it bad etiquette to do that after you had already put the work in to answer. If so, then apologies, I'll accept your answer as it does work.

Comment: @drstevok It's fine to wait for alternatives. On the edits, you have one : `'  a'`. I had one related comment on it earlier - Do you want it to be converted to `None`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150033/discussion-between-drstevok-and-divakar).