# Pandas substring using another column as the index

Tags: python, string, pandas, substring

I'm trying to use one column containing the start index to subselect a string column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'string': ['abcdef', 'bcdefg'], 'start_index': [3, 5]})
expected = pd.Series(['def', 'g'])
```

I know that you can substring with the following

```
df['string'].str[3:]
```

However, in my case, the start index may vary, so I tried:

```
df['string'].str[df['start_index']:]
```

But it return NaNs.

EDIT:
What if I don't want to use a loop / list comprehension; i.e. vectorized method preferred.

EDIT2:
In this small test case, it seems like list comprehension is faster.

```
from itertools import islice
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(islice(x.string, x.start_index, None)), 1)
%timeit pd.Series([x[y:] for x , y in zip(df.string,df.start_index) ])

631 µs ± 1.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
101 µs ± 233 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Do all strings have the same length?

Comment: No they do not.

Comment: Might take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042214/how-can-i-slice-each-element-of-a-numpy-array-of-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using for loop with `zip` of two columns , why we are using for loop here, you can check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care)

```
[x[y:] for x , y in zip(df.string,df.start_index) ]
Out[328]: ['def', 'g']
```

Comment: It's so slow solution that it's impractical for larger data sets

Comment: @LeszekZarna https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/are-for-loops-in-pandas-really-bad-when-should-i-care